# How to find a positive integer solution?

Tags: equation-solving

Is this the proper way?

```
f = 
  3*((A^3 + B^3) - (A^3 + B^3)^(2/3)*B -(A^3 + B^3)^(1/3)*A^2 + A^2*B) == 
  A^3 + B^3 + (A^3 + B^3) + 3*(A + B + (A^3 + B^3)^(1/3))*(AB + A(A^3 + B^3)^(1/3) + 
  B(A^3 + B^3)^(1/3)) - 3AB(A^3 + B^3)^(1/3)

FindInstance[{f, A > 0, B > 0, C > 0}, {A, B, C}, Integers, 5]
```

Comment: a and A are different symbols, as are b and B. Next, AB is interpreted as a single vairbale called AB (and you probably want A*B). Finally your symbol (1/3) should be written out as (1/3) just as you wrote out (2/3).

Comment: @bills thanks done

Comment: There are still `AB`s occurring in `f`. Anyways, replacing `AB` by `A B`, `Reduce[{f, A > 0, B > 0}, {A, B}, Integers]` returns `False`, telling me that there are no solutions.

Comment: You can simplify to `f = A^3 - 6 B C^2 - 3 B^2 C + B^3 == 3 A (B^2 + 2 B C + C^2 + 2 A C) && A^3 + B^3 == C^3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify to

```
f = A^3 - 6 B C^2 - 3 B^2 C + B^3 == 3 A (B^2 + 2 B C + C^2 + 2 A C) && A^3 + B^3 == C^3
```

but there are **no** positive solutions.  Define

```
f[A_, B_] := With[{c = (A^3 + B^3)^(1/3)}, 
             A^3 - 6 B c^2 - 3 B^2 c + B^3 - 3 A (B^2 + 2 B c + c^2 + 2 A c)];
```

and `Plot3D[ f[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]` makes it obvious that `f[x, y] < 0` for all positive values of `x` and `y`.